# why there is no gradient when the leaf tensor is updated

Tags: pytorch, gradient

The following is my toy example

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad = True)
y = x**2
y.backward(retain_graph = True)
print(x.grad)
x = x + 4
y.backward(retain_graph = True)
print(x.grad)
```

The first print prints the gradient of x, while the second print prints nothing. Why the gradient of x disappear after x is updated by x =  x + 4? Thanks.

---

### Newly added questions:

The following code could do what I want, which update x iteratively. However, I need to add x.requires_grad = True every time it is updated. Is there any better way without using x.requires_grad = True? Thanks.

```
x = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad = True)
y = x**2
y.backward(retain_graph = True)
with torch.no_grad():
  x = x + x.grad
x.requires_grad = True
y = x**2
y.backward(retain_graph = True)
print(x.grad)
```

---

### Update: my solution

```
x = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad = True)
y = x**2
y.backward(retain_graph = True)
print(x.grad)
x.data = x.data + x.grad.data
x.grad.zero_()
y = x**2
y.backward(retain_graph = True)
print(x.grad)
```

The result of the code is

```
tensor(6.)
tensor(18.)
```

, which is exactly what I want to have. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is mainly because `x=x+4` doesn't update the tensor; it creates a new tensor and assigns it to the variable `x`.

I changed the code to print the data pointer of the tensor in `x` before and after `x=x+4` as follows:

```
import torch
x = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad = True)
y = x**2
y.backward(retain_graph = True)
print(x.data_ptr())
print(x.grad)
z = x
x = x + 4
y.backward(retain_graph = True)
print(x.data_ptr())
print(x.grad)
print(x is z)
print(z.grad)
```

The output was:

```
3007755542592
tensor(6.)
3007755541184
None
False
tensor(12.)
```

First, you will notice that the data pointer of the tensor in `x` has changed after `x=x+4`. The is because `x+4` created a new tensor which is now what `x` holds.

Second, I kept the original tensor in another variable `z`. As you can see `x is z` returns `False` and the gradient of `z` has twice the gradient since `y.backward(retain_graph = True)` was called twice. `z` now holds the tensor which was in `x` before the line `x=x+4`.